# Upgrade from Bitcoin QT 0.8.5 to latest Bitcoin Core 0.15.X

Tags: bitcoin-core

I bought and transacted BTC in 2013/2014.  I had a Bitcoin QT 0.8.5 wallet.  I plugged it in and it updated correctly to the latest block.  It correctly showed my BTC balance.  I made a transaction without enough fees, which has sat unconfirmed for weeks now.  I decided to upgrade to the latest Bitcoin Core wallet and so downloaded it, checked the Checksum, and then loaded it.  I swapped out the wallet file with my backup of my original wallet.  For some reason, it only shows about 1/1000th of my BTC holding.  I have got the blockchain completely up to date.  There are no other transactions showing, only those I have made.  I have gone back to QT 0.8.5 and it still shows the correct balance when the blockchain updates.  What am I doing wrong in the latest Core version?

Comment: try dumpwallet command and then import private keys manually.

Comment: Thanks.  Just to clarify, what is the process? Assume I have my old wallet.dat file in the bitcoin directory.  Where to from there?

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand your question

Comment: Do I go into the latest Bitcoin Core0.15.X and go to Debug Window and type  bitcoin-cli dumpprivkey "myaddress"
then type bitcoin-cli importprivkey "mykey"

Comment: Exactly, Nothing more.

Comment: My wallet is encrypted, do I need to unlock it first.  I have tried the walletpassphrase command and I get Method not found (code -32601)

Comment: @bilbo After installing the new version of Bitcoin Core over the top of the previous version to do the upgrade, you should not need to replace your `wallet.dat` with the backup - but do make a fresh backup of your existing wallet before you start. Try staring the upgraded version of bitcoin-qt with the  `-rescan`  parameter if you are still missing coins. Let me know with @ reply if this helps and I will write it up as an answer.

Comment: @Willtech the coins are still missing

Answer (score 0):

Go to Bitcoin 0.8.5 Console Window and run :

```
dumpprivkey "myaddress"
```

Then in bitcoin 0.15.1

```
 importprivkey "mykey"
```

if you don't need to unlock your wallet even if it's encrypted since you are using Bitcoin-qt not RPC commands and you've already set your password when you started it.

if you don't want to use bitcoin-qt. go to terminal and run on v.8.5.0:

unlock your wallet if encrypted

```
(space)bitcoin-cli walletpassphrase "passphrase" timeout
```

Get private key of any address:

```
(space)bitcoin-cli dumpprivkey "myaddress"
```

if your wallet is encrypted run:

```
(space)bitcoin-cli walletpassphrase "passphrase" timeout
```

Then go to the latest version and run:

```
 (space)bitcoin-cli importprivkey "mykey"
```

The space before the commands is important to the command will never be saved to logs.

Comment: when I tried this with the space I got an error.  When I did it without the result was "null".  Is null the correct result or a fail?

Comment: are you on ubuntu?

Comment: No I am on Windows 10

Comment: that's why. ignore it or find an alternative.

Comment: OK so your solution was for Ubuntu?

Comment: "The space before the commands is important to the command will never be saved to logs." you can ignore it.